# Simple STRUCT program beginner QUESTIONS

Tags: c, arrays, struct, structure

So I just started learning struct type in C but I'm a bit confused. I have a pretty long program which I'm working on and I'm not sure to *how to insert a name and age into the next unused element in the arrray using a static variable (e.g. called nextinsert) inside the function to remember where the next unused element is.*

**This is the my code for the insert function.**

```
static void insert (struct person people[], char *name, int age)
{
  static int nextfreeplace = 0;
  static int nextinsert = 0;
  /* put name and age into the next free place in the array parameter here */
```

Comment: Pass a pointer to the indexed `people` in your main: `insert (&people[i], names[i], ages[i]);`. Since you have a counter in that loop, let the function that calls your `insert` take care of finding out what the next element in `people` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make it simpler: instead of trying to keep track of the index inside the `insert` function, you alreay have the index inside the `main` function. Thus:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* these arrays are just used to give the parameters to 'insert',
   to create the 'people' array */
#define HOW_MANY 7
#define MAXSTRLEN 32

/* declare your struct for a person here */
struct person
{ 
    char name [MAXSTRLEN];
    int age;
};

static void insert (struct person *people, char *name, int age)
{
  strncpy(people->name, name, MAXSTRLEN);
  people->age = age;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  // Move arrays here; if they are global instead, 
  // there would be need to pass name and age to insert()
  char *names[HOW_MANY]= {"Simon", "Suzie", "Alfred", "Chip", "John", "Tim",
              "Harriet"};
  int ages[HOW_MANY]= {22, 24, 106, 6, 18, 32, 24};
  /* declare the people array here */
  struct person people[12]; 

  int i;
  for (i =0; i < HOW_MANY; i++) 
  {
    insert (&people[i], names[i], ages[i]);
  }

  /* print the people array here*/
  for (i =0; i < HOW_MANY; i++)
  {
     printf("%s\n", people[i].name);
     printf("%d\n", people[i].age);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The `people->name` syntax is a shorthand for `(*people).name`. That is, you dereference the pointer to get to the actual struct (`*people`), and then access the struct number; because of operator precedence rules you need the parenthesis around `*people`.

I'm not sure how familiar you are with pointers, but in C, this is very common (passing a pointer to a struct into a function, and then using `structure->member` inside that function.

Of course, if your whole "exercise" revolves around learning about static variables, this may be of little value. But what I have here is likely preferred to keeping a static variable inside the function for array indexing.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your idea Evert. Indeed, your approach does seem a lot better than mine. However, I don't quite understand what the "->" means (for example people->age = age;).

Comment: Also, for some reason, both your version of the program and mine give me some really weird compliling errors: your version: arrays2.c:13: error: flexible array member not at end of struct
arrays2.c:17: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
arrays2.c: In function ‘insert’:
arrays2.c:21: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
arrays2.c:24: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
arrays2.c: In function ‘main’:
arrays2.c:42: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token

Comment: Sorry, I was lazy and didn't really check my program. A few fixes (semi-colon, properly define MAXSTRLEN and remove a few typo's I copied from you ;-) should do the trick.

Comment: Also added some info on pointers to structures, as per your question.

Answer (score 2):

For your question "how to insert a name and age", use:

```
strcpy(people[nextfreeplace],name);
people[nextfreeplace].age = age;
```

You may need to include `string.h` for `strcpy`.